# average of timestamp column not giving expected results

Tags: postgresql

In the following code, am I calculating average of the timestamp column correctly for each loc_id? The results seem a bit implausible, although they are in a readable format.

```
SELECT loc_id, AVG(timestamp::TIME) 
FROM dept_cluster_raw
group by loc_id
```

**Update:** This question has been solved. The results are plausible, I made a mistake in interpreting them, should I close the question?

Comment: Average on a time column does not really make sense to me. What is the average of "yesterday morning, today at noon and tomorrow evening"?

Comment: The data is of one day only

Comment: So what is the average of "this morning, afternoon and midnight"?

Comment: Since you discard the date portion, the result can kinda make sense. But I don't really see anything wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/dP2yx4mL

Comment: the average of 10 am, 12 pm, and 4 pm would be 1 pm! i.e. the middle value

Comment: try to convert as bigint and then calculate avg: SELECT AVG (cast(to_char((current_timestamp)::TIMESTAMP,'yyyymmddhhmiss') as BigInt))

Comment: That query should just work. If you think the results are implausible, please edit the question and show sample data, the result you are getting and why you think that the result is wrong. Note that `time` is a point in time, **not** a duration.

Comment: This question has been solved. The results are plausible, I made a mistake in interpreting them, should I close the question?

Comment: Yes close the question as it was never a complete question.